# Magento custom search form

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to create custom search functionality in Magento 1.9. Instead of writing it from scratch, I want to piggy back the default search functionality and add in custom filters. First I copied the form.min template and replaced with drop downs that I want to use.

form.custom.phtml:

```
<?php
$catalogSearchHelper =  $this->helper('catalogsearch');

$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();
?>

<form id="search_custom_form" action="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getResultUrl() ?>" method="get">

    <div class="select-box item">
        <label for="finder">GIFT FINDER</label>
        <select id="customS" name="finder">
            <option value="">Please select</option>
            <?php 
            foreach ($_categories as $key => $value) {
                echo("<option value='" . $value["name"] . "'>" . $value["name"] . "</option>");
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <label for="for">FOR</label>
        <select id="for">
            <option value="">Please select</option>
            <option value="him">HIM</option>
            <option value="her">HER</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div classs="item">
        <label for="delivery">DELIVERY OPTION</label>
        <select id="delivery">
            <option value="express">EXPRESS DELIVERY</option>
            <option value="standard">STANDARD POST</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div classs="item">
        <label for="price">DELIVERY OPTION</label>
        <select id="price">
            <option value="<250">LESS THAN £250</option>
            <option value=">250">MORE THAN £250</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Find') ?>" class="button search-button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Find') ?></span></span></button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_custom_form', '', '');
    //]]>
    </script>
</form>
```

I have included the above template on my home page using `{{block type="core/template" name="custom-search" as="custom-search" template="catalogsearch/form.custom.phtml"}}`, I have copied the core files into my own template folder and now I find myself stuck. 
Can anyone offer a better alternative or solution as to what I should do?

Thanks

Comment: As I am new in magento can you help me where to create a new file and paste the above content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a much easier option [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42066/how-to-display-the-advanced-search-on-the-front-page). I copied the catalogsearch folder to my theme, copied the advanced search form and placed it on my home page. Now I can customise the form and the query as I see fit.